# Why email doesn't work in Laravel ForgotPassword?

Tags: laravel, email

I'm working in laravel and i want to use its built-in feature for a forgotten password.
First, I just want you to send me an email. Whether or not that email is created. But it does not send and everything is fine with the settings.

ForgotPasswordController

```
/**
* Send a reset link to the given user.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function sendEmail(Request $request) {
    $this->sendResetLinkEmail($request);

    return Response::HTTP_OK;
}
```

I get the email but i don't get any message. Why?

Comment: Probably it's because your server or local has no smtp server configured and Laravel can't send the email.

Comment: The smtp server is configured. I have already used other email features with it and sent them without error